# Free AutoCad file converter for ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, autocad

I am looking for a free file converter which can convert my AutoCad (any format) file into SVG format, I found and tried 'LX-Viewer' but I don't know it has lots of set up settings, which is confused.
I also found 'DWG to DXF converter and convert only 'DWG to DXF' and vice versa as the name suggest. 
I did not find any free converter yet,

Any one have any idea about it.

Comment: Why was this question closed ??? Try DraftSight http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DraftSight , it's free (for non-commercial purposes) but not opensource. Dassault has an interesting piece of software there - supports export to SVG ! Download: http://www.3ds.com/products-services/draftsight/overview/

Answer (score 0):

Bit more than just a converter but maybe [FreeCAD](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/free-cad/index.php?title=Main_Page) might work

Comment: Thanks Joakim, but it does not convert files to SVG or any format, even i installed 'DraftSight' and has same problem. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I found this helpful software named [kabeja](http://kabeja.sourceforge.net/index.html)  which converts 'DXF' files into SVG, JPEG, PDF, etc. It can also be easily implemented in your Java code. I hope this will help.